# React Native Swipe To Enable Delete

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-swipe-list-view to have a delete button when I swipe my card to the left.
Is there anyway I can set the hiddenItem to grow/shrink when I swipe my card? Like when I swipe it to the left, the hidden on the right will steadily grow/scale to show.
The default seems to be a stack instead of shrink/grow the button.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely! While `react-native-swipe-list-view` offers convenient swipe actions, it doesn't directly support the scaling effect you're looking for. Here's how you can achieve this using a combination of techniques:

**1. Animated Values**

Utilize the Animated library from React Native to manage the animated scaling of your hidden item (the delete button in this case).
Create an Animated.Value to track the swipe progress.

**2. Gesture Responder**

Leverage the PanResponder API from React Native to:
Detect swipe gestures on your card component.
Update the Animated.Value based on the swipe distance.

**3. Styling and Transformation**

Map the Animated.Value to the scale of your hidden item using Animated.transform.

**Code Example**

```
 import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
 import { Animated, PanResponder, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react- 
 native';
 import SwipeListView from 'react-native-swipe-list-view';

 const MyCard = () => {
 const swipeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current; // Animation 
 value

  const [isSwiping, setIsSwiping] = useState(false);

  const panResponder = useRef(
  PanResponder.create({
  onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
  onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
  onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
    // Limit swipe to a certain distance for better control
    if (gestureState.dx < -50 && !isSwiping) { 
      setIsSwiping(true);
      swipeAnim.setValue(gestureState.dx / -100); // Map dx to scale 
     }
    },
    onPanResponderRelease: () => {
    Animated.spring(swipeAnim, { toValue: 0, useNativeDriver: true 
    }).start(); 
    setIsSwiping(false);
    },
    })
   ).current;

   const renderHiddenItem = () => (
    <Animated.View
    style={[styles.hiddenItem, { transform: [{ scaleX: swipeAnim }] }]}
    >
    <Text style={styles.hiddenItemText}>Delete</Text>
    </Animated.View>
    );

    return (
    <SwipeListView
    data={[{ key: '1', text: 'Item 1' }]}
    renderItem={(data) => (
    <View style={styles.card} {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
      <Text>{data.item.text}</Text>
     </View>
    )}
    renderHiddenItem={renderHiddenItem}
    leftOpenValue={-100} // Adjust this based on your button size
      />
     );
     };

     const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    // Add your styles for card, hiddenItem, hiddenItemText
    });

    export default MyCard;
```